# No audio to youtube stream using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, youtube, streaming, mobile-ffmpeg

My Stream File..

**stream.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash

VBR="1500k"
FPS="30"
QUAL="ultrafast"
YOUTUBE_URL=" rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"
YOUTUBE_KEY="**********"
VIDEO_SOURCE="video.mp4"
AUDIO_SOURCE="Selfish.mp3"
AUDIO_ENCODER="aac"


ffmpeg \
 -stream_loop -1 \
 -re \
 -i "$VIDEO_SOURCE" \
 -thread_queue_size 512 \
 -stream_loop -1 \
 -re \
 -i "$AUDIO_SOURCE" \
 -c:v libx264 -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS *2)) -b:v $VBR -bufsize 3000k -maxrate $VBR \
 -c:a $AUDIO_ENCODER -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -pix_fmt yuv420p \
 -f flv $YOUTUBE_URL/$YOUTUBE_KEY
```

Im sending audio from my client side.. But no audio coming to stream. But video is still working..

Output photo
[Preview Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNcIf.jpg)

Comment: Please add the ffmpeg log to your post. Also, `-re` should not be used (it's only for simulation purpose as doc says) and they could be detrimental to your purpose.

Comment: @kesh the logs showing me that audio is going to stream but in stream there is no audio.. Only video is running.. Im kinda new in ffmpeg it would be greate if you help me 